# how to display 2D arraylist in gridview

Tags: android, gridview, arraylist

I have created an arraylist and inserted some 2D array into it .. When I am trying to display that arraylist using GridView only the reference of the array object is showing . 
Here is my code :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   ArrayList<String[]> arlst=new ArrayList<String[]>();

   String ar1[]={"Sayantan","Shome"};
   String ar2[]={"Abhishek","Sarkar"};
   String ar3[]={"Bishal","Ghosh"}; 

  arlst.add(ar1);
  arlst.add(ar2);
  arlst.add(ar3);


      ArrayAdapter<String[]> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String[]>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arlst);
      gv.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

When I run the project and press the button then this is the output ----

[Ljava.lang.String;@45f4e610

[Ljava.lang.String;@45f4e6b8

[Ljava.lang.String;@45f4e760

---

How I can show the name into the Gridview ???

Comment: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/gridview/android-gridview-example/ go through this it will solve your problem

Comment: in this case you have to create your own adapterclass which extends base adapter

Answer (score 0):

The `ArrayAdapter` is only printing the `Object.toString()` value.There is actually two solutions for that.

1-Create your own custom class and override `toString()`method to print the string that concatenates the array elements.

2-Use a different type of adapter like `BaseAdapter`.